# Where to change order status messages in magento?

Tags: php, magento

I want to change the order status messages in the magento like pending, processing and complete to my customized message.
can someone suggest me how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a DB table `sales_order_status` which contains order status labels. You can modify these by using the translation system.

Create a `translate.csv` CSV in your theme's locale directory. [Example](http://developer.practicalecommerce.com/articles/1442-Tutorial-Use-Magento-s-Translation-CSV-File-to-Change-Site-Labels)

Then you create a line for each of the labels you want to change.

So if you wanted to change "Cancelled" to "Order Cancelled" you would create a line in the CSV that looked like

```
"Cancelled", "Order Cancelled"
```

The first item is the string to match, the second item is the replacement string.

I would advise using this method, rather than changing the strings in the DB, as it's more portable, and will prevent any unintended side effects of messing with the DB.

Comment: It's really great..can i change everything in the frontend with this file & is it good ?

Comment: Yep, you can use this method to modify any string that's passed through the translation helper. All of the core uses this helper. It's best practice to use this method as far as I know.

Comment: You can also have module specific translation, which is how the core does it, if you look under app/locale/en_US you will see all of the default translation files. The locale file name is defined in the module etc/config.xml

Answer (score 2):

You can directly change order status label from admin
just go to admin system choose order status and change order status from here

Comment: Huh, so you can. Well looks like I totally over-engineered my solution :)